# Creating an array of mp3 audio files in iOS and playing them at random with a UIButton

Tags: objective-c, xcode, arrays, ios5

I am attempting to create a prediction making iOS 5 iPhone App that will play a short (1-15 second long) Random mp3 audio clip from an array that can be triggered by a UIButton's touchUpInside event. I want to create an array with the mp3 files and then create a method that when called will play 1 file at random at a high volume. I have found a response to a similar question: [How do I call an array value and use it to play a sound file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1214420/how-do-i-call-an-array-value-and-use-it-to-play-a-sound-file) But I did not find the question or response to be clear enough or very helpful in my app. Does anybody know of the most efficient way I can go about creating the mp3 audio file array and then creating a method that will play a random clip back? Thanks in advance.

Comment: what's your problem? creating the array, the mp3 files, or choosing one at random?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to create the NSArray and randomize the mp3 file played using this code.
In my ViewController.h

```
`@property (strong, nonatomic) NSArray *soundsArray;
```

Then in my ViewController.m in the viewDidLoad method

```
self.soundsArray =[[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"sound1", @"sound2", nil];
```

And I randomized the sounds in an IBAction using,

```
NSUInteger index = arc4random_uniform(self.soundsArray.count);

    NSString *filePath = [self.guySoundsArray objectAtIndex:index];
    NSString *soundFilePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:filePath ofType: @"mp3"];
    NSURL *fileURL = [[NSURL alloc] initFileURLWithPath: soundFilePath];
```